# Check if there are scheduled tasks with Angular2 and Zone.js

Tags: angular

Is there any way to check if there are scheduled task using Angular2 and Zone.js?

Let's say I have this component

```
import...

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {

  public myMethod() {
    console.log('enter my method');
    setTimeout(function() { console.log('task1'); }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() { console.log('task2'); }, 1500);
  }

}
```

and I want be notified when both `task1` and `task2` are completed.

In my app component I'm subscribed to `onUnstable` and `onStable` events in this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [MyComponent],
  template: `<mycmp></mycmp>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
    console.log('start app component constructor');

    zone.onUnstable.subscribe(function(args){
      console.log('enter unstable');
    });

    zone.onStable.subscribe(function(args){
      console.log('enter stable');
    });
  }
}
```

So, when I call `myMethod()` what I expect is this sequence of logs:

```
enter unstable
enter my method
task1
task2
enter stable
```

but I get this:

```
enter unstable
enter my method
enter stable
enter unstable
task1
enter stable
enter unstable
task2
enter stable
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to interpret the results.

There are total three micro tasks here.

Task1

`public myMethod() {  ...  }`

Task2

`setTimeout(function() { console.log('task1'); }, 1000);`

Task3

`setTimeout(function() { console.log('task2'); }, 1500);`

The first three lines are related to Task1 start and completion.

The next three lines are related to Task2 start and completion.

The final three lines are related to Task3 start and completion.

Each of the async operations including event handler that may be calling `myMethod` create a new microtask

Comment: Ok, the why I get that logs is clear but, is there a way to get notified once all three tasks are done?